# Windows 7 upgrade needs to uninstall programs

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from Vista to Windows 7 (both Home Premium).  The installer stops and tells me I need to uninstall the following two programs: 'Verisoft Access Manager' and 'HP Imagezone'.  However, neither of them are listed in the Control Panel Uninstall list, and I cannot find any registry entries for them either.  So I am stuck.

I really don't want to do a clean install, as the computer doesn't belong to me and I don't want to mess anything up for the owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went into Google and typed the following: `Verisoft Access Manager remove`

[Turns out](http://vip.asus.com/forum/view.aspx?id=20090930172843703&board_id=3&model=F3Sg&SLanguage=en-us&page=1) that it's part of "Asus Security Protect Manager", which you can remove from your system.

Regarding the HP software, it's probably part of an all-in-one printer software package that you'll need to remove.